# wireless door opening detection

Tags: sensor, wireless

I need to find a way to detect when a door is opened and i want to register that through a wifi connection. So the 'door detection' module should send data to a PC over wifi when a door is opened.

There may be better solutions to get this working, but the first thing that came to my mind is an arduino board. Is there an arduino board that is easily capable detecting when a door is opened and sending data on detection to a PC (wireless)??

Or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Digi [Xbee WiFi modules](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi#specs) have 10 digital I/O channels and ADC on board to operate autonomously, so you don't need a SBC like Arduino.

[image]

Connect one of the I/Os with a pull-up resistor to a microswitch to detect the door's state.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to focus how you want to solve WiFi connectivity. The opening door detection will be easy with respect to that. Try searching the Internet for 'arduino wifi shield' and you'll get a lot of hits on shields that will support WiFi.

Personally I wouldn't go for the WiFi (or ethernet) solution. It is complex not only to physically build, but also the (webserver? and) client side software that you need. I experimented with a Bluetooth transceiver, which is reasonably easy to implement, but the range with my module was with about 10m a bit short.

**EDIT:**

Coming to think about it, I have 2 433MHz radios that easily connect to arduino and PC. They have a range of up to 1000m. [Radio communication module](http://www.iprototype.nl/products/components/communications/apc220-radio-communication)

Answer (score 0):

If WiFi or Bluetooth are a bit short range then [this device](http://www.gt.honeywell.com/en-us/Pages/Product.aspx?category=InstalledTerminals&cat=HSM-GLOBALTRACKING&pid=SAT-202) can be connected to a door open switch and used to report the event to your pc.  The door can be pretty much anywhere apart from the polar ice caps.

Comment: It's a nice device, but a bit of a overkill for what i want :-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: A **$1150** satellite tracker to detect an open door? There are many longer range radios for a fraction of that price. I also don't see the use of a satellite position tracker for a door.

Comment: @Federico - If your door is on a lorry carrying a full load of top of the range motorcycles then knowing where the door is when it is opened is probably quite useful.  Compared to the value of the load $1150 (if that is the price) can look cheap.

Comment: But OP doesn't mention a scenario like this, so we can safely assume the door is on a fixed location in a building also on a fixed location. Your assumptions are far-fetched at least. And, sorry about the -1, but they make your answer not useful.

Comment: @Federico - My original answer was slightly tongue in cheek but many Governments and trucking companies find it very useful.  Cellphone data network based products cover the minority of the earth's surface, particularly when you are working in hot, dusty and dangerous parts of the world where trucks are prone to hijack.

Comment: I'm not denying that, but I don't think it's a useful answer for most users here on Electronics.Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xbee modules for stevenvh's [suggested solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/35027/9455), but if you're dead set on using WiFi
[this module](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN_XV) can have analogue and digital input without an external Microcontroller.

Obviously it will consume more power than the Xbee modules, but it has the advantage of not requiring an external Xbee adapter connected to the PC.

Comment: Actually that RN-XV module consumes even LESS current than the Xbee Wifi modules, so it's preferable on that front... Also, it seems there are more documentation and community projects out there for the RN-XV than the Xbee Wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but i'm looking for an easy to build inexpensive system for solving almost exactly the same problem.  I've had quite a bit of success using the nRF24L01 tranceivers with the available [RF24 library by maniacbug](http://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/getting-started-rf24/).  I'm currently working on two solutions: one uses arduino nanos with the RF24 transceivers with leaf nodes acting as sensors and multiple hub/routers for receiving and aggregating data into my security system.

The hubs can overlap and even receive the same data depending on the distance away from the sensor but the system accounts for that.  Another approach i've considered is to have each sensor act as node on a mesh network but that requires more work and the use of another [library](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24Network/) that i've yet to start looking at..

[image: nRF24L01+]

The benefit is that these radios cost from $1.50 to $3.00 apiece usually sold as a 2pc set for $6 where the Xbee modules listed above cost from $25 to $60 for just one.

I'm not sure if my response is timely enough but I believe its a better solution than the Xbee approach if cost is a consideration.

Comment: I've found these usefull, too, but they aren't wifi.  Something like the esp8266 is both wifi (to an extent) and similarly cheap (since only one is needed).  With effort, it may even work without an additional MCU.

Comment: I need to look into that...that might change the way I build my system.  Very nice!

Comment: Ok...so some pretty serious downsides to this approach.  The esp8266 requires separate power...the arduino can't provide enough directly from the board.  Also, running the device off of batteries is pretty much out of the picture which is a huge + for the rf24s...but there are parts of the system that might be worth converting.  All in all the esp8266 is very interesting!  Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty generic 433mhz door/window alarm sensors [like PB-67R](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Cheap-Price-Slim-Design-433mhz-Wireless-Door-Window-Magnetic-Contact-Sensor-for-433MHz-GSM-PSTN-Alarme/32799841397.html).

To receive the signal, all you need is e.g. WeMos D1 (has WiFi) and a $1 433mhz receiver e.g. WL101-341.

P.S.: Note that PB-67R wouldn't ping you when the door is closed.